# Maximum Absolute Difference

Tags: arrays

**You are given an array of N integers, A1, A2 ,…, AN. Return maximum value of f(i, j) for all 1 ≤ i, j ≤ N.
f(i, j) is defined as |A[i] - A[j]| + |i - j|, where |x| denotes absolute value of x.**

> For example,
>       `A=[1, 3, -1]
>       f(1, 1) = f(2, 2) = f(3, 3) = 0
>       f(1, 2) = f(2, 1) = |1 - 3| + |1 - 2| = 3
>       f(1, 3) = f(3, 1) = |1 - (-1)| + |1 - 3| = 4
>       f(2, 3) = f(3, 2) = |3 - (-1)| + |2 - 3| = 5
>       So, we return 5.`
>   https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/maximum-absolute-difference/

```
int Solution::maxArr(vector<int> &A) {

    int size = A.size();
    int max_diff = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i ; j < size ; j++)
        {
            int diff = abs(A[i]-A[j])+abs(i-j);
            max_diff = max(max_diff,diff);
        }

    }
    return max_diff;
}
```

There are many question on stack overflow with same title but none of them is properly answered.
Above code shows time limit exceeded.Also i am not getting the question properly.I ve come up with this sol with a little understanding and equation suggested in question.It passes the sample test cases but for the rest of cases its time limit exceeded.
Any help in understanding the ques and where i am getting wrong in my solution will be appreciated.ed.